# Is there a function to change the sharpness of a Picture via VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have taken a large number of pictures. For all of these Pictures i want to change contrast, brightness and sharpness with a macro.

With my current code I can already change the contrast and the brightness to my chosen value. My problem is that I don´t know/find a command to change the sharpness of the picture?

I tried guessing the command with this: `.IncrementSharpness 0.1` but that does´t work i guess.

```
For n = 1 To 3
  Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(z)
  With myDocument.Shapes(1).PictureFormat
    .CropBottom = 285    
    .CropLeft = 170    
    .CropRight = 225    
    .CropTop = 250    
    .IncrementContrast 0.3    
    .IncrementBrightness 0.1    
  End With
  z = z + 1
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/317825/macro-to-sharpen-all-images-in-word-document  may work in Powerpoint

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the command i need is .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften) ? Or how can I put this in my original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
For n = 1 To 3

  Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(Z)
  Set shp = myDocument.Shapes(1)
  With shp.PictureFormat
    .CropBottom = 10
    .CropLeft = 10
    .CropRight = 10
    .CropTop = 10
    .IncrementContrast 0.3
    .IncrementBrightness 0.1
  End With

  With shp.Fill.PictureEffects
    Dim eff As PictureEffect
    Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
    eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = -0.5
  End With


  Z = Z + 1
Next n
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Code worked as intended. How can i mark this as solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Willams for the pointer, here's the PowerPoint version:

```
Dim eff As PictureEffect
With myDocument.Shapes(1).Fill.PictureEffects
  Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
  eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.1
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !